# How to define features presence in a TensorFlow Data Validation schema?

Tags: python, tensorflow, metadata, feature-engineering, tensorflow-data-validation

I want to create a new [TensorFlow Data Validation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started) schema from scratch with fixed features name, type and presence.

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

# Initialisation
my_schem=schema_pb2.Schema()

# New features (one per available type)
for k in schema_pb2.FeatureType.items():
    my_schem.feature.add(name=f'feat_{k[1]}', type=k[0])

tfdv.display_schema(schema=my_schem)
```

The code above returns the following schema:

| Feature name | Type | Presence | Valency | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'feat_0' | TYPE_UNKNOWN |  |  | - |
| 'feat_1' | BYTES |  |  | - |
| 'feat_2' | INT |  |  | - |
| 'feat_3' | FLOAT |  |  | - |
| 'feat_4' | STRUCT |  |  | - |

How can I set a Presence property to my features ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [FeaturePresence documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tf_metadata/api_docs/python/tfmd/proto/schema_pb2/FeaturePresence), two arguments are possible:

1. `min_fraction`: minimum fraction of examples that have this feature
2. `min_count` : minimum number of examples that have this feature

If `min_fraction=1`, 100% of examples need to have this feature, i.e. the feature is **required**.
If not, the feature is **optional**.

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

# Initialisation
my_schem=schema_pb2.Schema()

# A new required feature
my_schem.feature.add(name='required_feat', type='INT', presence=schema_pb2.FeaturePresence(min_fraction=1))

# A new optional feature
my_schem.feature.add(name='optional_feat', type='INT', presence=schema_pb2.FeaturePresence(min_fraction=0.5))

tfdv.display_schema(schema=my_schem)
```

The code above returns the following schema:

| Feature name | Type | Presence | Valency | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'required_feat' | INT | required |  | - |
| 'optional_feat' | INT | optional |  | - |